# Why we need such a restrictions in logics?

Tags: logic, philosophy

Note:I am not competent is logic so this question may look weird to you.
So as I know there are different types of logics (first-order logic, second-order...), and the difference between them is that each next order logic can quantify over bigger set of objects, and now the question which I have is, why we need such a restriction? Why we can't make logic where we could quantify over all objects? My intuition suggests me that this would bring some paradoxes, is it the real reason, if so is it the only one? If it's not, what is the reason for such restrictions in every logic?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The first full version of *predicate logic* (see [Frege](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/frege-theorem/#S1)) was "high-order" (also if second-order was sufficient for Frege's project). The basic divide is between FOL, which has some very "nice" properties and [Second-order and Higher-order Logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-higher-order/).

Comment: But is not "quantify over bigger set of objects" but on higher types of objects : FOL quantifies over individual objects only; SOL quantifies also on properties of indivuduals; TOL over properties of properties of individuals; and so on. See also [Type Theories](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/type-theory/#ParaRussTypeTheo).

Comment: See Melvin Fitting, [Types Tableaus and Gödel’s God](https://books.google.it/books?id=9XWB7OywK1oC&pg=PA1), Kluwer (2002) for a modern treatment.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Then I formulated it in the wrong way, but the question still arises, what is the reason for such restriction?

Comment: What "restrictions" ? If you want to use Higher-order logic with quantification on properties of every order, you can use it.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Then, what is the motivation to look at logics where you can quantify only on individuals or only on properties of individuals?

Comment: You can see I.Jané, [A critical appraisal of second-order logic](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/01445349308837210) as well as Stewart Shapiro, [Second-order Logic and First-order Logic](https://academic.oup.com/philmat/article-abstract/7/1/42/1430601?redirectedFrom=PDF).

Comment: I don't think it's a weird question. It's even an interesting one. I'm not sure but I think the reasons are mainly historical. The separation still makes sense because we sometimes want to study concepts which are strictly first-order of second-order. Different phenomena happens and philosophical questions arise depending on the restrictions. For instance (order 0) we have pure logic (order 1) we introduce a class of individuals, what are they? How do we justify their existence? (strict order 2) more powerful but without individuals...

Comment: In most math textbooks (e.g. in real analysis), author's routinely quantify over objects including functions, but not over predicates -- somewhere between FOL (which doesn't quantify over functions or predicates) and SOL (which quantifies over both functions and predicates). There just doesn't seem to be any  crying need to quantify over predicates in mathematics.

Comment: If you can quantify over functions, you can "fake" quantifying over predicates, e.g. instead of P(x) (where P is a predicate), you could write p(x)=1. Yes, it would look very odd, but it would allow you to quantify over p.

Comment: @DanChristensen Quantifying over sets (and more generally relations) is the set-theoretic analogue of quantifying over predicates, and it is done all the time e.g. sets of open sets or defining the transitive closure of a relation as the smallest relation such that ... Functions are also sets in a set-theoretic foundations, so quantifying over them is no more or less higher-order than quantifying over relations or sets. Outside of a set-theoretic foundations, quantifying over functions may be truly higher-order, but in that context you'll likely also find yourself quantifying over predicates.

Comment: @DerekElkins I have often seen quantifying over functions (and sets) in math textbooks, but I don't recall ever seeing quantifying over predicates. There doesn't seem to be any need for it.

Comment: @DanChristensen My point is that quantifying over sets *is* quantifying over predicates. Some higher-than-first-order logics are even formulated as quantifying over "sets" rather than predicates (though, personally, I *strongly* discourage this). Also, if one conflates predicate and relation, then "the smallest relation" means a quantification over relations (i.e. predicates). If you reply, "well a relation is just a set", then so are functions and then there's nothing higher-order about quantifying over them.

Comment: @DerekElkins What problems if any might mathematicians encounter if they quantify over sets and functions, as they seem to do with impunity?

Comment: @DanChristensen What are you talking about? At what point did I suggest that there would be some "problems" doing any of this? Responding again to your original comment: In standard foundations, i.e. ZFC, functions *are* sets. In ZFC, where the individuals are sets, quantifying over functions is no more higher-order than quantifying over any other set. The reason mathematicians don't feel a "crying need" for predicates is because sets were *designed to* serve the role of predicates. The original unrestricted comprehension axiom basically identified sets as reifications of predicates.

Comment: @DanChristensen I think if we terminologically separate the logical functions from the set-theoretic functions (call the latter mappings), then the inconsistency in your original comment becomes clearer. If we take "function" to mean logical function in your comment, then it is not true that mathematicians commonly quantify over them, but it is true that it would require a higher-order logic to do this quantification. If we take "function" to mean mapping, then it is true that mathematicians commonly quantify over them, but it is not true that it would require a higher-order logic to do so.

Comment: Not an expert on this either, but my impression was that SOL is able to quantify over formulas of FOL ... that is, in SOL, you can say something like $\forall \varphi$ where $\varphi$ is a FOL formula.   As such, you can't introduce the language all at once: you first need to have FOL defined before you can define SOL .... but like I said, I could be talking out of my ass here. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than look specifically at higher- versus first-order logic, let me focus on a broader point: there is a fundamental tension between **expressiveness** and **tameness**, and the former isn't always of greater importance.

For example, first-order logic is [compact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compactness_theorem): if $\Gamma$ is a set of first-order sentences, then $\Gamma$ has a model iff every finite subset of $\Gamma$ has a model. Put another way, first-order logic admits a notion of "finitely long proof," since if $\Gamma$ entails $\varphi$ then some finite subset of $\Gamma$ entails $\varphi$ (apply compactness to $\Gamma\cup\{\neg\varphi\}$). Second-order logic meanwhile is not compact, since we can write a sentence $\theta$ in second-order logic which is true in exactly the finite structures (it's a good exercise to prove this, and show that this leads to a failure of compactness).

So more power is not always a good thing: metatheorems about first-order logic, made possible by the *restrictiveness* of that logic, lead to consequences for classes of structures defined by first-order-expressible conditions. In general we want to strike a balance between power and expressiveness, and this can be quite tricky.

---

At this point it's a good idea to look at a specific application of the tameness of first-order logic: the [Ax-Grothendieck theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ax%E2%80%93Grothendieck_theorem). We want to show that every injective polynomial function $\mathbb{C}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ is surjective. To do this, we argue as follows:

- First, we prove - purely algebraically - that the result holds when we replace $\mathbb{C}$ with the algebraic closure of a finite field.
- Next, we note that "injectivity implies surjectivity for polynomials" is expressible by a set of first-order sentences: there is a first-order theory $\Gamma$ such that whenever $F$ is a field, $F\models\Gamma$ iff every injective polynomial $F^n\rightarrow F$ is surjective.
- Now we apply compactness to get an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero satisfying $\Gamma$.
- But such a field is first-order equivalent to $\mathbb{C}$, and so we get that $\mathbb{C}\models\Gamma$, and we're done.

Note that it was crucial that we be able to fit the property we care about into a tame logical framework so that we could pass from the weak examples we could establish purely algebraically to the thing we actually care about.

---

The general study of logics beyond first-order, and abstract properties of logic, is [abstract model theory](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pl/1235417263). One of the first serious results in the subject was [Lindstrom's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindstr%C3%B6m%27s_theorem), which showed that first-order logic is maximally strong with respect to a couple important tameness properties.

The best-behaved logic extending first-order logic is generally agreed to be the [infinitary logic $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1,\omega}$](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-infinitary/), which has applications throughout descriptive set theory, computability theory, and even the model and proof theory of first-order logic itself. It also has some nice tameness properties of its own - nothing quite as good as first-order logic, but still much better than second-order logic (which is terrible in several ways). [Dependence logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-dependence/) and its relatives provide another example of a reasonably tame extension of FOL.

On the other hand, logics *weaker* than first-order logic also crop up, since they often enjoy tameness properties which first-order logic lacks. For example, by Godel we know that first-order logic isn't decidable; however, it has decidable *fragments* which are still reasonably expressive, and which play serious roles in computer science. And decidability is merely one of the tameness properties we can get by restricting first-order logic (another very important one is the *finite model property*).

Theoretically, we could also care about logics *incomparable* in strength to first-order logic. These do indeed exist. However, I don't know of any actually interesting examples (I've only ever seen them show up as weird counterexamples).

---

It's worth noting that in the above I'm talking only about *technical* tameness properties. There are also *philosophical* issues here, and much ink has been spilled over whether second-order logic is "meaningful" in the same way that first-order logic is (and more generally, to what extent **quantification** is something we can actually do in any serious sense). While these issues are quite interesting, I'm leaving them aside since I think that it's much more compelling, at least initially, to see purely mathematical issues: we can't sweep aside the role of compactness in Ax-Grothendieck by adopting a different philosophical perspective, we're actually forced to confront the mathematical aspects of logic itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you collapse first-order and second-order, meaning that every property of objects (i.e. a sentence with an object parameter) is itself an object, and you have a collection $Prop$ of all properties, then you can obviously get Russell's paradox by constructing $R(x) :≡ x{∈}Prop ∧ ¬x(x)$. Clearly $R$ is a property and so $R(R) ≡ ¬R(R)$, which is a contradiction. Alternatively, using quantification over $Prop$ instead of membership in $Prop$ we can construct $S(x) :≡ ∃Q{∈}Prop\ ( x=Q ∧ ¬Q(Q) )$ and deduce the following: If $S(S)$ then let $C{∈}Prop$ such that $( S=C ∧ ¬C(C) )$, which gives $¬S(S)$. If $¬S(S)$ then trivially $∃Q{∈}Prop\ ( S=Q ∧ ¬Q(Q) )$ and hence $S(S)$. Either way a contradiction.

To evade both variants, you must restrict which properties are objects (as in ZFC or MK), or must not assume classical logic. For instance, if you switch to 3-valued logic, then the natural conclusion is that $Prop$ does not have boolean membership, so $R(R)$ can be $null$. And similarly equality may not be boolean, so "$S=Q$" may be $null$.